# Spring Boot Exception evaluating SpringEL expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

> ERROR 4904 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine
>   : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template
>   "index": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class
>   path resource [templates/index.html]")
>
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
>   during template parsing (template: "class path resource
>   [templates/index.html]")  at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
>   [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
>   [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
>   [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
>   [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]

---

> Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating
>   SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')
>   and #authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''USER'')')" (template:
>   "fragments/navbar" - line 8, col 15)

---

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

---

Problem comes from here when I try to check the authority

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="thymeleaf.org"> 
<th:block th:fragment="navbar">
    <th:block if:sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
        <th:block th:replace="fragments/navbar-guest"></th:block>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()') and #authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''USER'')')}">
        <th:block th:replace="fragments/navbar-user"></th:block>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()') and #authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''ADMIN'')')}">
        <th:block th:replace="fragments/navbar-admin"></th:block>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()') and #authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''MODERATOR'')')}">
        <th:block th:replace="fragments/navbar-user"></th:block>
    </th:block>
</th:block>
```

Comment: can you add a snippet of index template?

Comment: <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<th:block th:fragment="navbar">
    <th:block
            th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()') and #authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''USER'')')}">
        <th:block th:replace="fragments/navbar-user"></th:block>
    </th:block>
    <th:block
            th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()') and #authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''ADMIN'')')}">
        <th:block th:replace="fragments/navbar-admin"></th:block>
    </th:block>

Comment: can you post it inside the post? and please try to format your text before posting

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you **thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4** in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and **xmlns:sec in the html template** in thymeleaf page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass authorization in model like as below-

> set parameters on the controller

```
request.setAttribute("authorization", authorizationObject);
```

> use the same on the fron-end as below

```
<th:block th:if="${authorization.isAuthenticated() && authorization.hasAuthority('USER')}">
        <th:block th:replace="fragments/navbar-user"></th:block>
</th:block>
```

Hope it will be helpful, Thanks

Comment: how do I get the authorizationObject

Comment: It helped I just added interceptor with the Object

Answer (score 0):

I added interceptor which on every request sends the Role

```
modelAndView.addObject("authorization", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream().findFirst().get().toString());
```

and in the HTML I check with `<th:block th:if="${authorization=='USER'}">
        <th:block th:replace="fragments/navbar-user"></th:block>
    </th:block>`

For now everything works !